# Chrome and Opera creating small padding when using display:table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, opera

I've noticed that Chrome (34.0.1847.131 m) and Opera (21.0.1432.67) are creating an small gap between two `divs` when using the property `display:table;`. (and not when using `display:block`, for example)

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/1/) reproducing it. (adjust the width of the panel, it doesn't take place with every width)

[image]

To reproduce it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    left: 0px;
}
.right {
    right:0px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    background:#000;

    display:table;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

How can I get rid of this gap? Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Question at the end of it :)

Comment: half pixel cannot be drawn , so if you have a width wih an odd value, 1px is missing in chrome and in ff it seems to be given to one or an another container : http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/4/

Comment: @GCyrillus why doesn't it happen then if I set the property to `display:block`: http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/5/?

Comment: hm.. building on @GCyrillus's comment, Avoiding the problem, you could set one of the blocks with 51%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 1 px to the placement of the right div:

```
.right {
    right:1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/12/

Comment: Looks like a quite simple solution. Adding `right:0.1px` seems to work as well.

Comment: You can't do .1px... try .1em or rem as those are units you can adjust with decimal places and fractional units. It is a weird issue and it seems to be touched on in a roundabout way in a few chromium bug reports. Nothing specific to this, but certainly in the area. There is, no doubt, an issue with the `display:table;` setting in chrome. If you feel it served you well, and solved your issue, feel free to accept.

Comment: Yeah, now I will :) Thanks for it! One hour is needed for the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `table` to `table-cell` seemed to do the trick:
http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/7/

Comment: But I can't change it for `table-cell`... I need `table`.

Comment: Why do you need the `table` value for the `display` property? You don't even need `display` to make it work as you want.

Comment: @MattSmith to center content vertically (within an innner table-cell) and to get the 100% with of the container. (which table-cell doesn't)

Comment: Well, it's just as @GCyrillus said in the comments above, "half pixel cannot be drawn , so if you have a width wih an odd value, 1px is missing in chrome and in ff it seems to be given to one or an another container" -- This is solved when using `table-cell` because they know to share the width which causes the extra pixel to be distributed to either/or. You should really rethink the way you're going about doing this layout.

Comment: OP needs the display:table as part of his template.

Comment: Maybe you could learn to read the comments, and deduce that we all already know that.

Comment: I agree with Nick Dugger's comments. Maybe this is just a matter that needs to be refactored in the manner in which you're coding it. You don't need `table` to get 100% width of the container; `block` works that way, too and you don't need to add `right: 1px` which is hacking it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two potential solutions:

**Option 1:**

Use [css calc();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the width of the two divs, like so:

[Working Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/17/)

```
.left, .right {
    width: calc(50% + 0.1px); /* Important bit */
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    background:#000;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use JavaScript to set the width of the two divs, like so:

[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3z24S/18/)

```
wid = function () {
    $('.left, .right').width(Math.ceil($(window).width() / 2)); //Math.ceil() will round the value up
};
$(document).ready(wid);
$(window).resize(wid);
```

If you can get away with using `calc()` its probably the better option, using JavaScript seems expensive for something like this.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a matter of `vertical-align` and known height, you can do without `display:table/table-cell;` **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/htpyw)** or you could do without `absolute` `position`.

You may use `inline-block`, `vertical-align` and pseudo élément.
HTML :

```
<div class="left">
  <div class='content'>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class='content'>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

the div.content will be inline-block or is display:table-cell in your problem.

CSS

```
.left {
    left: 0px;
}
.right {
    right:0px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    background:#000;
    color:white;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.left:before,
.right:before ,
.content {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-width:95%;
}
.left:before,
.right:before {
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  width:0;
}
```

*Even answering here to your question , i still do not understand why position:absolute; and still not sure if elements are suppose to have an known height. It looks more like you are not using the proper or best method to your needs.*

The pixel bug is, in my opinion, already  answered in comments and obviously a different way for chrome to handle this display value.

Comment: Can't you set the `width:100%` for the `.content`? http://jsfiddle.net/PzNf7/1/ There's a gap there.

Comment: @Alvaro , yes you can if you reset font-size to 0 on parent to avoid white-space showing up in between pseudo and .content. http://jsfiddle.net/PzNf7/2/

Comment: Thanks, but it sounds a bit tedious for my purposes to make it work properly as a template. I believe I will end up choosing to add `0.1px` of margin to the right panel and keep using my `table` structure to center the content.

Comment: Well you have infos and comments plenty enough to choose yourself what you wanna do , i'd say it's always been up to you :)